# Play RTSP through VLC in VS2010 on 64bit machine

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, plugins, rtsp, vlc

I am trying to play an RTSP stream on a Win form application on a 64 bit windows machine. I have added the VLC player as a COM component. But when i even try to play a stored video file it does not play.

```
axVLCPlugin1.addTarget("C:\\wildlife.wmv",
                       null,
                       AXVLC.VLCPlaylistMode.VLCPlayListReplaceAndGo,
                       0);
axVLCPlugin1.play();
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: You're missing some code and details in your post.

Comment: axVLCPlugin1.addTarget("C:\\wildlife.wmv", null, AXVLC.VLCPlaylistMode.VLCPlayListReplaceAndGo, 0);            axVLCPlugin1.play();  This is the code i add to play a video file.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct DLL? You might be using the 32bit DLL, and that won't work. You'll have to either compile specific for x86 or else use the 64bit version. (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da/csharplanguage/thread/00ee5c83-b6d5-4bc1-836c-079b3e5d1199)

Comment: I am using the 32-bit DLL. But i want it to run on 64 bit. I don't want to change anything in the configuration manager. Where can i download the 64 bit DLL?

Comment: I also tried on 32bit machine also. it doesn't work there either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding "file:///" before the filepath. That should get it to play from a file.

Once that works, you can use VLC to create an RTSP stream.
1. in VLC, go to Media->stream
2. Under the File tab, click "Add" and select a video you wish to stream.
3. At the bottom, there is a button with a dropdown. Select stream and then click the button.
4. A window will pop up showing the source file path. Click "Next"
5. This window is where you select the output. Change the dropdown from "File" to "RTSP" and click "Add"
6. Choose a port number and a path. I will leave the port as 8554 and set the path to "/Test"
7. Click "Next" then click "Stream" You should see the VLC player start running, but the video will not play.

If you want to test to make sure the stream is working properly you can open another instance of vlc to view the stream.
1. Go to Media->Open Network Stream
2. enter "rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/Test" as the network url.
3. Click play and it should begin streaming.

After verifying that the stream is running, close the second instance of VLC and in your application, set those two lines of code to be:

```
axVLCPlugin1.addTarget("rtsp://172.16.10.50:8554/Test", null, VLCPlaylistMode.VLCPlayListReplaceAndGo, 0);
axVLCPlugin1.Play();
```

Comment: Thanks!..i tried adding "file:///" but it still does not work. And for the rtsp streaming the address is: rtsp://192.168.10.222:554/live.sdp. The solution for rtsp doesn't work either.

Comment: It could be the version of VLC that you are using then. When I tested it I was using 2.0.5

Comment: i was using version 2.0.4. Now i downloaded the new version. is it the same code:             axVLCPlugin1.addTarget("C:\\file:///wildlife.wmv",
                       null,
                       AXVLC.VLCPlaylistMode.VLCPlayListReplaceAndGo,
                       0);
            axVLCPlugin1.play();

Comment: "file:///" should go before the file path, so it should read more along the lines of "file:///c:\\wildlife.wmv". By running an rtsp stream, do you mean starting a stream to to read from or reading an existing stream?

Comment: The RTSP streaming is also exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: I have one more question: This works for a 32 bit system. Should i download a different DLL for a 64 bit system?

Answer (score 0):

I did a lot of research and found out that this is the best solution for playing RTSP streams on windows 64 bit machine through VS2010 - [VLCDotNet](https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet)

I am still looking for something similar in C++.